# My google analytics Event tracking code is not working?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have used Google analytics event tracking code for my website but the event is not responding.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" size="25" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form_Submit', 'Click', 'Submit']);">
```

I have two different pages in my website and i don't know what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, are you using classic GA our Universal analytics? A common mistake is to use classic GA syntax when you are in fact using universal analytics. The syntax for UA should be

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Form_Submit', 'Click', 'Submit')
```